# Ghost story film

Tags: story-identification, ghost

I'm trying to identify the following film if possible (I watched this ghost story a couple of years ago on TV).

All I remember is:

It started with a guy getting into a new apartment, the previous owner having met an untimely end about which no one wants to talk about.

As the story progresses he meets first the child of a neighbour's family who continuously plays with a ball on the floor, then the mother of said child and the brutal father who turns out to be a cop.

He gets wind of brutal beatings the woman receives from her jealous man. Once he even called the police... but the apartment turned out to be empty!

What followed were a number of situations where the guy thought he is going insane, at least until he understood that the whole family were ghosts. The father murdered the two and then killed himself.

What is more is that nobody interfered or helped... which he in the end does (which the previous owner of his own apartment didn't, which caused his death). He loses out but survives. The father gets dispersed and the mother and child manage to move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are describing the 2008 film *[The Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Echo_(2008_film))*, which is a remake of a Filipino film.

Points that match:

- Abusive cop next door with wife and daughter
- Officer beat wife and daughter to death
- Nobody helped which led to haunting

Final part of the film matches your description of the helping and moving on:

> Hector, while looking for Bobby, dies by falling down a staircase after running from Carly's ghost. Alyssa, also haunted by the ghosts, runs to Bobby's apartment looking for him, but winds up being dragged to Room 517 by the ghost of Walter, mimicking the way Gina was murdered. Bobby hears Alyssa's screams of pain, and saves her. While tending to her back in his room, Bobby witnesses the scene as it had occurred those years ago; yet, this time, Bobby doesn't let the entire scene play out and rushes to intervene just as Walter is about to give the final blow to Gina. Gina then beats Walter to death with his nightstick and disappears along with her daughter. With the ghosts gone, Bobby comforts Alyssa as the police head towards the apartment.

Comment: yepp that was it. tnx!